# TCL: searching a list for elements containing a particular character using lsearch

Tags: list, tcl

In the following list:

```
{12 34 23 54 67 75 46}
```

Using ***lsearch***, what is the search pattern to be used for finding all the elements from this list which has the number ***'4'*** in it?

(i.e the output should return {34 54 46})

Comment: You should post what you have tried when asking, next time (see the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: [lsearch](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm)

You can use:

```
 set newlist [lsearch -all -inline -glob $mylist *4*]
```

`-glob` is the default, I put it in for documentation purposes.

`-all` indicates to return all results, not just the first match.

`-inline` indicates to return the list as the result.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Brad Lanam will work if you know what you are matching will not contain any characters with a special meaning to glob. If that is not guaranteed, you can use:

```
set newlist [lsearch -all -inline -regexp $mylist (?q)4]
```

The (?q) makes anything following it a literal string. So no special interpretation of any characters will happen. But a regular expression is not anchored by default, so the string can appear anywhere in the list elements to match.